# What is the @ used for while installing node modules?

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, package, redux-offline

I noticed that while trying to install [redux-offline](https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline), the documentation says to install the package using :

`npm install --save @redux-offline/redux-offline`


While this [article](https://medium.com/better-programming/offline-first-react-app-b79ab1a17649) says to install the package without the '@' before package name

`npm install --save redux-offline`

I wanted to know what the difference is between both, if any.

Comment: That's package scope. Read more here: https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/scope.html . THe package `redux-offline` might have been moved to `@redux-offline` scope, that's why you need to use the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@redux-offline/redux-offline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@redux-offline/redux-offline) here you can read this quote

> Redux Offline is now being maintained by a community-driven team. The new versions of the library will now be available under the npm organization @redux-offline. Big thank you to @jevakallio for creating this amazing library in the first place.

As you can see here [redux-offline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-offline), this package updated 3 years ago, when [@redux-offline/redux-offline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@redux-offline/redux-offline) updated 3 months ago.

If you want to use this lib, use `@redux-offline/redux-offline` as this package is updating with the community.